# DataAdapter Update not properly Inserting data into SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, merge, ado.net

I have 2 `DataTables`: 1 that is filled with all the data from a table in my database called `Ticket_Report`, and a second one that is filled with new tickets.

I am searching the `Ticket_report` datatable for duplicates from the new ticket DataTable (and deleting them). Then I merge the new tickets datatable into the `Ticket_report` datatable.

I then try and Update the Ticket_Report table in SQL Server with the newly edited `Ticket_report` datatable. I am expecting the Update method to Update the table in SQL Server with rows that have matching primary keys from the datatable, and Insert rows that don't exist.

I am not getting any errors, however it doesn't seem like the rows are being updated/inserted.

```
con.Open();
DataTable ticketReportDT = new DataTable();
ticketReportDT = newTicketdt.Clone();
ticketReportDT.Columns[0].Unique = true;

SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ticket_report", con);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);

da.Fill(ticketReportDT);
da.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommandBuilder(da).GetUpdateCommand();

int currentTicketCount = ticketReportDT.Rows.Count;//3234
int newTicketCount = newTicketdt.Rows.Count; //339

//Removing Duplicate tickets in ticketReportDt
foreach (DataRow NewTicketsRow in newTicketdt.Rows)
{
   foreach (DataRow currentTicketsRow in ticketReportDT.Select())
    {
        if (currentTicketsRow.Field<string>(ticketReportDT.Columns[0]) == NewTicketsRow.Field<string>(newTicketdt.Columns[0]))
        {
            currentTicketsRow.Delete();
        }
    }
}

ticketReportDT.AcceptChanges();
int currentTicketCount2 = ticketReportDT.Rows.Count;//2903, is less than last count because duplicates removed

ticketReportDT.Merge(newTicketdt);//add new tickets to ticketReportDT
ticketReportDT.AcceptChanges();

int currentTicketCount3 = ticketReportDT.Rows.Count;//3242, count went up because new tickets added

da.Update(ticketReportDT);//apply changes to database table Ticket_Report
con.Close();
Console.WriteLine("Ticket Transfer Complete");
```

This runs without error. To test, I did a count query in SQL Server before and after this update.

Before update:

```
select count(*) from TICKET_REPORT
// = 3234
```

After Update:

```
select count(*) from TICKET_REPORT
// = 3234 <-Should be 3242 (row count of ticketReportDT)
```

It seems like the Datatable has the correct amount of rows, but when I do the update, this does not reflect in SQL Server. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: More interested n seeing what your UPDATE Command looks like  also to remove rows from a datatable you should be using a for loop that decrements for example 
`for (int i = ticketReportDT.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                DataRow row = csvData.Rows[i];  //Remove
                if (ticketReportDT.Rows[i][0].ToString() == NewTicketsRow.Field<string>(newTicketdt.Columns[0])
                {
                    ticketReportDT.Rows.Remove(row);
                }
            }`

Comment: @MethodMan I added what the command builder generated

Comment: @MethodMan And I have seen that statement before about removing rows. What is the advantage of doing it with a for loop instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have called ticketReportDT.AcceptChanges() before updating database it is not going to update anything in the database.

Comment: I needed to call AcceptChanges() to apply the deletion of the rows I marked as .Delete(). It wont actually delete the rows until I AcceptChanges(). Do I need to switch up the order that I am calling things?

Comment: I added another ticketReportDT.AcceptChanges(); after the da.Update and still nothing has been added.

Comment: When you call AcceptChanges() it only deletes it from the dataset (not database). Instead of calling AcceptChanges call da.Update() which will internally call AcceptChanges after updating the database.

Comment: When I removed all .AcceptChanges() and only use  da.Update(ticketReportDT), I am getting a new error:  "String or binary data would be truncated".

Comment: This means that some string column has values more than column is allowing in the database. Make sure datatype length is same between two tables.